# Rails kaminari routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, kaminari

I have such action in controller:

```
class ArtLookupsController < ApplicationController
  def search
****
@pre_articles_result = ArtLookup.search(s_query)
@articles_result = Kaminari.paginate_array(@pre_articles_result).page(params[:page]).per(70)
***
end
end
```

and route:

```
  match '/search' => 'art_lookups#search', :as => :search_art_lookup
```

And part of view:

```
  = paginate @articles_result
```

When i insert some text to seach, i get results, all is ok, limited by 70 entries
(link is: ****:3000/search)
.... But when i click on other pages, for example 3-rd link is like: :3000/art_lookups/search?authenticity_token=ve%2FrRQoXIHPQ9BAN07RLCMF59bB0HVlEcNn%2Flxd4f64%3D&page=3&search=1234&utf8=✓

and i get error: `Unknown action The action 'show' could not be found for ArtLookupsController`
But why? How can i solve this? So that if i click on page number, i get other results... ?
also i tried `match '/search(/:page)' => 'art_lookups#search', :as => :search_art_lookup`

Comment: hm.... doesn't anybody know?

Comment: I hit this same Kaminari problem when I had a 'post' route, and the pagination was trying a 'get' on subsequent pages.  I changed the form to issue a 'get' and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I consider you could modify your routes.rb like this:

match '/search(/:page)' => 'artLookups#search', :controller => 'artLookups', :action => 'search'

Comment: I have tried the method above. Though it'll work when you click the "Next" or "2" link, you may get error when clicking "First" link.

Comment: I think you may try: match '/artLookups/search', :controller=>'artLookups', :action=>'search'